# Hibernate JPA Annotations 1 to 0..1 relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to setup a 1to0..1 (zero or one) relationship, but am running into issues.

Now my assumption is to use the @OneToMany, and not @OneToOne.

Basically I want my "child" table to hold the foreign key to the "parent" (I use child and parent very loosely). I never need to load "children" standalone

This is the basic table structure I want to achieve

```
ITEM {
  ID
  RELATED_ITEM_ID
}

INVOICE {
  ID
}
CATALOGUE {
  ID
}
```

Reprsented as Java classes like the following

```
class Item {
...
}

class Invoice {
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL })
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @JoinColumn(name="RELATED_ITEM_ID", nullable=false)
  Set<Item> items;
}

class Catalogue {
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL })
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @JoinColumn(name="RELATED_ITEM_ID", nullable=false)
  Set<Item> items;
}
```

The above code, if I only have Invoice or Catalogue registered in hibernate will create the tables as I want, and work perfectly. However, as soon as I have both Invoice and Catalogue registered, hibernate throws me the error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of _itemsBackref found in package.name.Item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of ended up cheating to get this to work how I want. I dont ideally want a hierachy like that, but I need to get this working, and I feel this is a compromise with working around hibernate.

```
ITEM {
  ID
  RELATED_ITEM_ID
  DTYPE
}

INVOICE {
  ID
}

CATALOGUE {
  ID
}
```

Reprsented as Java classes like the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RECIPIENTS")
abstract class Item {
  ...
}

@Entity
  public class InvoiceItem extends Item {
}

@Entity
  public class CatalogueItem extends Item {
}


class Invoice {
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL })
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @JoinColumn(name="RELATED_ITEM_ID", nullable=false)
  Set<InvoiceItem> items;
}

class Catalogue {
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL })
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @JoinColumn(name="RELATED_ITEM_ID", nullable=false)
  Set<CatalogueItem> items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to map this schema with Hibernate (at least, as long as `Customer` and `Recepient` don't extend the same entity).

It would be much easier to use the following schema instead:

```
ADDRESSES {
  ID
}

CUSTOMER {
  ID
  ADDRESS_ID
}
RECIPIENT {
  ID
  ADDRESS_ID
}
```

---

```
class Customer {
  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL })
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID")
  Address address;
}

class Recipient {
  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL })
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID")
  Address address;
}
```

Comment: I probably shouldnt have used address as my example, address storage is complicated. Storing a foreign to to an address is a common trap that comes to bite you down the road. I have updated my original post.